# generating human-readable file sizes from a find command

Tags: linux, bash

I'm pulling list of largest files recursively with this statement:

```
sudo find 11 -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -10
```

Business folks would like this in a human readable format (similar to the content that ls -lrth provides) -- I've tinkered with syntax but can't quite get it to provide similar results.

Comment: You can use find ... -ls` to produce ls-style output.

Comment: The output you currently have seems more "human readable" than the output of `ls -lrth`.  Can you clarify what you want for the output?

Comment: I want the K, M, G notation for kilobytes, etc., etc

Comment: Is the `sudo` strictly required? (If the files you're trying to find aren't reachable without it, that impacts what it takes for an answer to be correct).

Answer (score 3):

[GNU core utilities - numfmt](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html#numfmt-invocation)

> **numfmt**: Reformat numbers numfmt reads numbers in various representations and reformats them as requested. The most common usage
> is converting numbers to/from human representation (e.g. ‘4G’ →
> ‘4,000,000,000’).

```
sudo find 11 -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" |
  sort -n |
  tail -10 |
  numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --format="%.3f"
```

To show some examples demonstrating how this works:

```
$ numfmt --to=iec --suffix=B --format="%.3f" 49532
48.372KB

$ numfmt --to=iec --suffix=B --format="%.3f" 49532058
47.238MB

# iec-i with i "GiB"
$ numfmt --to=iec-i --suffix=B --format="%.3f" 4953205800
4.614GiB

# iec without i "GB"
$ numfmt --to=iec --suffix=B --format="%.3f" 4953205800
4.614GB
```

Comment: Very nice. This doesn't require a second privilege-escalated command, because it's converting the data that `find` identified on the initial pass.

Comment: Someone who was paranoid about dangerous filenames might change it to `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%s\t%p\0' | sort -nz | tail -z -n -10 | numfmt -z --to=iec-i --suffix=B --format='%.3f' | tr '\0' '\n'` to NUL-delimit things while they're in the pipeline.

Comment: I got this error when trying to run this:

numfmt: invalid format ‘%.3f’, directive must be %['][-][N]f

Comment: @user3299633 it's the version probably. `v8.22` (`2013`) returns the error you mentioned ("`...directive must be %['][-][N]f`"). Yet, `v8.32` (`2020`) executes successfully (supports directive `%[0]['][-][N][.][N]f`).